# How do I store a pygame keyboard input value in a varibale

Tags: python, pygame

How do I store a pygame keyboard input value in a variable.
In the place `pygame.K_r` how can I use my key variable to assign to the key input.

```
import pygame
import random
from sys import exit

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        **key = "r"**
        key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key_input[pygame.**K_r**]:
            pass


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the enumerator constant in a variable:

```py
key = pygame.K_r
```

and that variable for subscription and get status from sequence:

```py
key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if key_input[key]:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it Out,

```
import random
from sys import exit
import pygame

pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
        
        R = pygame.K_r    # variable R is used to assign the pygame keypress K_r
        key_input = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key_input[R]:   #use varibale R to check if r is pressed
            print('Pressed')


    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```